# How to get index of subscribed object in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I'm writing an app in which I subscribe to an object. Now in the html I have a delete button and want it to delete an element with an index of it.

So far I have an undefined index. How can I work this out?

this is the component with subscription:

```
    timeInputs: timeInput[];
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private sub: Subscription;
    timeInputIndex: number;
    editedTimeInput: timeInput;

ngOnInit() {
        this.timeInputs = this.ttService.getTimeInputs();
        this.subscription = this.ttService.timeInputsChanged.subscribe(
            (timeInputs: timeInput[] ) => {
                this.timeInputs = timeInputs;
            }
        );
        this.sub = this.ttService.startedEditing.subscribe(
            (index: number) => {
                this.timeInputIndex = index;
                this.editedTimeInput = this.ttService.getTimeInput(index);
            }
        )
}

onDelete() {
        this.ttService.deleteTimeInput(this.timeInputIndex);
    }
```

service.ts

```
    startedEditing = new Subject<number>();

    getTimeInputs() {
        return this.timeInputs.slice();
    }

    getTimeInput(index: number) {
        return this.timeInputs[index];
    }

    deleteTimeInput(index: number) {
        this.timeInputs.splice(index, 1);
        this.timeInputsChanged.next(this.timeInputs.slice());
    }
```

when I try `console.log(this.timeInputIndex);` the output is undefined, so the deleteTimeInput function deletes the first element. How to change the code so that I get the index of an element which I click on - which I want to delete?

EDIT:
here is the shortened part with click listeners

```
<form class="mt-3" *ngFor="let timeInput of timeInputs">
<div class="dropdown show">
                <a
                        role="button"
                        id="dots"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v otherIcon"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onDuplicate()">Duplicate</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onDelete()">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello Natalia! You'd need to show us the template with the click listeners to have a realistic chance of helping you. One thing that might help – if you're rendering your time inputs using an `ngFor` directive, you can access the index there. As in `*ngFor="let obj of objects; i = index"`

Comment: sorry, didn't think this is important, but I just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I see you're doing something interesting with RxJS, specifically with the "startedEditing" Subject, but I never see that subject use `.next()`. Nor is it clear to me how it would know what the index was.

For a more parochial approach, you can just pass the 'index' value straight to your onDelete() function. To do so, within your ngFor directive you do the following:

```
<form class="mt-3" *ngFor="let timeInput of timeInputs; i = index">
```

Then when you call delete

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onDelete(i)">Delete</a>
```

Now in your onDelete function you have access to the index

```
onDelete(i) {
    this.ttService.deleteTimeInput(i);
}
```

Now maybe that answer isn't to your liking, and you would rather use your RxJS solution. You'll somehow need to have the service send data using `startedEditing.next(index)`, but as to how you know what index to use, you'll probably still need the `ngFor="let timeInput of timeInputs; i = index">` solution.

Let me know if I've completely misunderstood what you need!